# UnknownHostException Android utf-8 encoding URL

Tags: java, android, url, unicode

```
String url = String.format("http://%s.jpg.to", URLEncoder.encode("свинья", "utf-8"));
new URL(url).openStream();
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
```

I want to read web page with russian symbols in URL, but catch exception (Android 4.1.1):

```
W/System.err: java.net.UnknownHostException: http://%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8C%D1%8F.jpg.to
W/System.err:     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.<init>(HttpConnection.java:283)
W/System.err:     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
W/System.err:     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:315)
W/System.err:     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:310)
W/System.err:     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:289)
W/System.err:     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:239)
W/System.err:     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:80)
W/System.err:     at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:563)
W/System.err:     at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:540)
W/System.err:     at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:227)
W/System.err:     at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:216)
W/System.err:     at test.jpgto.MainActivity$RetrieveImageTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:63)
W/System.err:     at test.jpgto.MainActivity$RetrieveImageTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:49)
W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

But link http://2.jpg.to/ (for example) works fine. What i doing wrong?

Comment: What does `URLEncoder.encode("свинья", "utf-8")` print on your side?

Comment: %D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8C%D1%8F

Comment: and out link works in browser fine http://%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8C%D1%8F.jpg.to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
            String url = String.format("http://%s.jpg.to", IDN.toASCII("свинья"));
```

we are see link http://xn--b1ampn2ds.jpg.to

Answer (score 1):

What happens when you simply put the characters as they are on the URL?
For instance, try something like this:

```
String host = "свинья";    
//here we now do string-formatting and then call the convertUrlToPunycodeIfNeeded which uses IDN
String url= convertUrlToPunycodeIfNeeded(String.format("http://%s.jpg.to", host));
//then simply use the URL
new URL(url).openStream();
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
```

Below is the code showing how to use java.net.IDN in your case:

```
    //The translation of characters to their Latin equivalent
   public static String convertUrlToPunycodeIfNeeded(String url) {
        if (!Charset.forName("US-ASCII").newEncoder().canEncode(url)) {
            if (url.toLowerCase().startsWith("http://")) {
                url = "http://" + IDN.toASCII(url.substring(7));
            } else if (url.toLowerCase().startsWith("https://")) {
                url = "https://" + IDN.toASCII(url.substring(8));
            } else {
                url = IDN.toASCII(url);
            }
        }
        return url;
    }
```

I have found this nice example [here](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=java.net.IDN) - **Example 1**:

Comment: i will try this on real device... wait, please, 2 mins

Comment: on real device this exception too

Comment: I made some changes to the code - could you please try that and let me know if it helps or if the error persists.

Comment: You can simply write "utf-8" instead. By the way, is this an accurate translation of the characters: `svin’ja`?

Comment: :// symbols are encoded =)
java.net.MalformedURLException: Protocol not found: http%3A%2F%2F%D1%80.jpg.to

Comment: word "свинья" translating as "pig"

Comment: I have found a translation example - let's try it and see how far we get. Please check updated answer.

Comment: i was answer about this in #7 comment

Comment: in updated code link svinja.jpg.to is not equals свинья.jpg.to

Comment: So the URL should point to `http://свинья.jpg.to` and not its equivalent? When I put the URL on the browser, it changes to `http://xn--b1ampn2ds.jpg.to/` - is this what you expect to happen in code as well?

Comment: yes, thats right!
                String url = String.format("http://%s.jpg.to", "xn--b1ampn2ds");
how i can encode anything word?

Comment: You are right, I updated the code with the use of IDN and when I tried it, it does resolve correctly. Please try it out.